# Trying to do a Vlookup with a value of another column as a column number - Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, match, vlookup

Got 2 Dataframes

df1

| City | Number |
| --- | --- |
| LON | 1 |
| NYC | 2 |
| TOK | 3 |

df2

| City | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LON | A | D | G |
| NYC | B | E | H |
| TOK | C | F | I |

What I'm trying to do is add a column to the end of df1 which would use the 'Number' Value as a column header for Df2

So for example The new column 'Letter' would:

-lookup TOK & 3 from df1 in df2 and return the Value I
-lookup LON & 1 from df1 in df2 and return the Value A

New df1:

df1

| City | Number | Letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LON | 1 | A |
| NYC | 2 | E |
| TOK | 3 | I |

Comment: please provide the expected output, but likely solved in the duplicate

Comment: @jezrael I think `lookup` is now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

Comment: Provided expected output. i don't think the highlighted duplicates resolve my question

Comment: `melt` df2 to create Number/Letter columns and `merge` on City/Number